# Comments for github flavored markdown with vim-commentary

Tags: filetype-markdown, plugin-vim-commentary

[`vim-commentary`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) is a great plugin for commenting and uncommenting lines. However if some filetype isn't supported, as per documentation, one can do the following: (see [FAQ](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary#faq))

```
autocmd FileType apache setlocal commentstring=#\ %s
```

Currently for markdown commenting adds `%%` in front of a line.

```
%% a comment
```

I want to use comment from github flavoured markdown, i.e., like this:

```
<!-- a comment -->
```

I am not getting how to change `commentrstring` for markdown to get the above. Any help will be appreciated.

---

**Edit:** The problem seems to originate from the plugin [vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki), `:verbose set ft? cms?` says:

```
filetype=vimwiki
      Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vimwiki/autoload/vimwiki/u.vim line 142
commentstring=%%%s
      Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vimwiki/ftplugin/vimwiki.vim line 12
```

I am using vimwiki with markdown extension, so it changes filetypes to `vimwiki`. I have put the following line in `.vimrc`, now it works:

```
autocmd FileType vimwiki setlocal commentstring=<!--%s-->
```

Comment: The runtimes that come with Vim already set `'commentstring'` for Markdown to use `<!--%s-->` comments, see here: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/ftplugin/markdown.vim#L12 . Are you sure it's using different comments for you? Please [edit] the question to also post the output of `:verbose set ft? cms?` , that should help us debug your issue.

Comment: Edited. It works now. Thanks! But it's weird that vimwiki changes the filetype all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the specific issue you've been having is caused by Vimwiki taking over the Markdown file type globally. You have a few options to prevent Vimwiki from doing that, which should help you solve your issue.

First, you could set the [`g:vimwiki_global_ext`](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/v2.5/doc/vimwiki.txt#L2631) variable to 0, disabling it from hooking into files *anywhere* with those specific extensions. You can do so by adding this to your vimrc file:

```
let g:vimwiki_global_ext = 0
```

This means [temporary wikis](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/v2.5/doc/vimwiki.txt#L2631) will not be created on the fly anymore, so you'll need to use the [`g:vimwiki_list`](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/v2.5/doc/vimwiki.txt#L2631) variable to register the locations where you want Vimwiki to be activated. This should be straightforward if you're mainly using Vimwiki to manage a single wiki or a handful of them and you don't tend to create new ones, but rather add more contents to the ones you have.

The other option you have is to use a different set of extensions for Vimwiki that doesn't clash with the usual Markdown types. For example, you could use something like `*.wiki` or `*.vimwiki`. In order to configure that, you need to set the [`g:vimwiki_ext2syntax`](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/v2.5/doc/vimwiki.txt#L2631) variable. You set it to a Dictionary which maps specific extensions to the Vimwiki syntax type you would like to associate with that extension. (You can use `'markdown'` for the default, or `'media'` for MediaWiki syntax.)

Either option should help fix the issue for you. If you don't plan to create Vimwikis on the fly, go with the former. If, on the other hand, you would like to be able to create them dynamically, but on the other hand you're fine with using a file extension different from the default ones, then go with the latter.

Comment: I don't plan to create vimwikis on the fly, so I decided to go with the first one. But I have run into another problem, due to plugins: [vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc) and [vim-pandoc-syntax](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax). Now `:verbose set ft?` shows `filetype=pandoc         Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vim-pandoc/ftdetect/pandoc.vim line 5`. So I decided to change it by adding `let g:pandoc#filetypes#pandoc_markdown = 0` to `.vimrc`. But still `set ft?` shows `pandoc`.

Comment: The problem is basic markdown stuff doesn't work with `pandoc` filetype, like: lists (I have to add `-` or `2.` manually for every new list entry)

Comment: @MahbubAlam Make sure you don't have some kind of "sessions" plug-ins making your pandoc rules "stick" even though you reconfigured the global variable that should prevent them from being set... Is that possible that this is what's causing it now?

Comment: By "sessions" plugin do you mean mappings will stay throughout my vim session? Then I don't think I have any "sessions" plugin. I did quit vim completely, and then open again, still same problem.

Comment: https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc/issues/342#issuecomment-633226987